# How to put result of Promise.all at specific place?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, promise.all

Is there any way to use Promise.all in my case ?
Should i use two different loop (one to push in an array of promise and another to push each result to the right place) ?

(This is just an example and my current code contains much more data, so using Promise.all seems very interesting since the requests are independent of each other)

```
const  myFunction = async ()=>{

    let someData=[{ID:55,name:'name1',firstname:'fname1',address:'address1'},
                  {ID:26,name:'name2',firstname:'fname2',address:'address2'},
                  {ID:88,name:'name3',firstname:'fname3',address:'address3'}]
    
    for (let i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
       someData[i].country = await getCountryFromDatabase(someData[i].ID)
      }

    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the array to an array of promises, using the reference to the object you have in the mapping callback to mutate it after the API call finishes.

```
let someData = [{ ID: 55, name: 'name1', firstname: 'fname1', address: 'address1' },
    { ID: 26, name: 'name2', firstname: 'fname2', address: 'address2' },
    { ID: 88, name: 'name3', firstname: 'fname3', address: 'address3' }]
await Promise.all(
    someData.map(obj => (
        getCountryFromDatabase(obj.ID).then((country) => {
            obj.country = country;
        })
    ))
);
```